# How do you capture multiple entities and add into context in array form?

Tags: entities, watson-conversation

For example, here's the sentence:

> I would like to order 1 large chicken burger with 10 chicken wings and 14 pepsi

I would like to put them into context as follows:

```
{
"burgers" : [
    {
        "amount" : 1,
        "size" : "large",
        "item" : "chicken"
    }
],
"drinks" : [
    {
        "item" : "pepsi",
        "amount" : 14
    }
],
"sides" : [
    {
        "item" : "chicken wings",
        "amount" : 10
    }
]
}
```

This is easily done from the code perspective as location is mentioned in the entities, but how can this be done directly on conversation. Is it possible?

Comment: Is this what you only want in the context or is there more? My guess is that you either have to process it in the app or use a two-step approach. I have use nested processing to first extract important items, then post-process it. See https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/watson-conversation-variables#nested-evaluation-of-variables

Comment: I'm thinking of, user can add orders such as:

` I would like to add 3 scramble eggs `

this would add another item in sides with 
` { "item" : "scramble eggs", "amount" : 3 } `

If this can be done on conversation directly, it'll be great. Otherwise, I'll just process the entities from the app itself.

Answer (score 0):

That's something you have to arrange yourself after getting the response from Watson.

Aside from your entities, `burgers, drinks and sides`, you'll also need to set up a `quantity` entity but the only way to actually recognize which goes with which, meaning, what quantity is for burgers, drinks and sides is assuming something by their locations.

You could assume every quantity comes before the actual food/drink.

Comment: yup.. that's what I thought. And instead of simply assign a 1-to-1 quantity to item, i really have to use the location property because sometimes, they might not put the quantity before the item, for example: I would like to order 1 double cheese burger with fries please.